# Is is possible to have a candlestick chart and a line chart on the same XY axis with apexcharts?

Tags: reactjs, series, candlestick-chart, apexcharts

I'm using the apexcharts with react to build a chart with two series: one is the price and it should be visualized as a candlestick chart and the other one is the volume and it should be visualized as bar (or line) chart. Is it possible to have both on the same XY axis?

I know that it is possible having two (or more) line charts on the same XY axis as in the attached picture, but I did not see an example for a candlestick chart.
[image: Apex Charts - multiple series]
For this example I would like to replace the red line with a candlestick chart.

Comment: https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/candlestick/ according to this it is possible. just that the data format for the red line will have to be slightly different.
IF you add a sandbox I can take a look